# Help requested to solve the integral $\mathop \smallint \nolimits_0^\infty {\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{{a{x^2} + b}}{{cx + d}}} \right){\rm{d}}x$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I am trying to find a way to solve the integral

$$\int_0^\infty  {\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{{a{x^2} + b}}{{cx + d}}} \right){\rm{d}}x$$

It is easy to solve the integral when I remove $d$ from the denominator,

$$\int_0^\infty  {\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{{a{x^2} + b}}{{cx}}} \right){\rm{d}}x = 2\sqrt {\frac{b}{a}} {K_1}\left( {\frac{{2\sqrt {ab} }}{c}} \right)$$

However, I can't find a solution when I add or subtract anything from $cx$ in the denominator.

Could you please help me with any way to solve or approximate the integral? Any direction will be much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Set $a := 1$ to make this a very important challenge. My two cents …

Comment: Substituting $x=u-c/d$ gives a nicer form, but the region of the integral changes. And Wolfram Alpha can't find an expression for even $\int_1^\infty \exp(-x-1/x) dx$ in terms of other functions.

Comment: If you multiply the negative sign into $c,d$ and expand $e^y=\sum\limits_{n=0}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n!}$, the indefinite integral uses a [sum of Appell $\text F_1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=integral+c%5En+%28%28x%5E2%2Bb%29%2F%28x%2Bd%2Fc%29%29%5En%2Fn%21) functions. The question is how to apply the $\int_0^\infty$ bounds

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I shall assume that all $(a,b,c,d)$ are positive. Let first $\beta=\frac b a$ $\gamma=\frac ca$, $\delta=\frac d a$
$$\int_0^\infty  {\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{{a{x^2} + b}}{{cx + d}}} \right){\rm{d}}x=\int_0^\infty  {\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{x^2+\beta }{\gamma  x+\delta }} \right){\rm{d}}x$$

A *possible* idea would be to expand the integrand as a series around $\delta=0$

$${\rm{exp}}\left( { - \frac{x^2+\beta }{\gamma  x+\delta }} \right)=e^{-\frac{x^2+\beta }{\gamma  x}}\Bigg[1+\frac{\beta +x^2}{\gamma ^2 x^2} \delta+\frac{\left(\beta +x^2\right) \left(\beta +x^2-2 \gamma  x\right)}{2 \gamma ^4 x^4} \delta^2+O(\delta^3)\Bigg]$$

Truncated to this level, it would give
$$2 \sqrt{\beta } K_1\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma }\right)+\frac{4 \sqrt{\beta
   }   K_1\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma }\right)}{\gamma ^2}\delta-\frac{2
   \left(\gamma  K_0\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma }\right)-2
   \sqrt{\beta } K_1\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma }\right)\right)}{\gamma
   ^4}\delta ^2+O\left(\delta ^3\right)$$  Expanding again with respect to $x$, we have
$$\Bigg[\cdots\Bigg]=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \alpha_n \,x^{-n}$$ and
$$\int_0^\infty x^{-n}\,e^{-\frac{x^2+\beta }{\gamma  x}}=2 \beta ^{\frac{1-n}{2}} K_{n-1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma
   }\right)$$ I supose that only $ K_{0}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma
   }\right)$ and $ K_{1}\left(\frac{2 \sqrt{\beta }}{\gamma
   }\right)$ will remain.

For a quick  test, using $\beta=2$ and $\gamma=3$ and the expansion to $O\left(\delta ^5\right)$, some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
\delta & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0.0 & 1.87883 & 1.87883 \\
 0.1 & 1.92070 & 1.92070 \\
 0.2 & 1.96280 & 1.96280 \\
 0.3 & 2.00510 & 2.00508 \\
 0.4 & 2.04758 & 2.04744 \\
 0.5 & 2.09021 & 2.08968 \\
 0.6 & 2.13296 & 2.13156 \\
 0.7 & 2.17582 & 2.17289 \\
 0.8 & 2.21876 & 2.21355 \\
 0.9 & 2.26176 & 2.25343 \\
 1.0 & 2.30478 & 2.29250 \\
 1.1 & 2.34781 & 2.33071 \\
 1.2 & 2.39081 & 2.36808 \\
 1.3 & 2.43378 & 2.40461 \\
 1.4 & 2.47667 & 2.44033 \\
 1.5 & 2.51948 & 2.47525 \\
 1.6 & 2.56216 & 2.50941 \\
 1.7 & 2.60470 & 2.54283 \\
 1.8 & 2.64708 & 2.57555 \\
 1.9 & 2.68926 & 2.60760 \\
 2.0 & 2.73123 & 2.63899
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Could you please clarify how did you expand the fraction inside the integrand? Apology I am not familiar with this expansion. What does $O\left(\delta ^n\right)$ stand for?

Comment: @MK71. It is just the Taylor expansion around $\delta=0$

Answer (score 0):

Defining the [incomplete Bessel function](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0377042707002014) as

$$
K_\nu(x,y) = \int_1^{\infty} t^{-\left(\nu+1 \right)}e^{-\left(xt + \frac{y}{t} \right)}\, \mathrm{d}t
$$
We get
\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-\frac{ax^2+b}{cx+d}} \, \mathrm{d}x & \overset{\color{purple}{x = \frac{d}{c}(t - 1)}}{=}\frac{d}{c}e^{\frac{2ad}{c^2}} \int_{1}^{\infty}e^{-\left[\left( \frac{ad}{c^2}\right)t + \left(\frac{ad}{c^2} + \frac{b}{d} \right)\frac{1}{t} \right]}\, \mathrm{d}t\\
& =\boxed{\frac{d}{c}e^{\frac{2ah}{c^2}} K_{-1}\left(\frac{ad}{c^2},\frac{ad}{c^2} + \frac{b}{d}\right)}
\end{align}